# java.lang.NumberFormatException (parse.Int)

Tags: android

An app published on market has an error:

java.lang.NumberFormatException

below the stack.

Is the cause this code?

```
fade = Integer.parseInt(ListPreference);
```

I see "OTHER" devices has affected by this crash. Any idea?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app/com.example.app.Notify}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1659)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3768)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:362)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
at com.example.app.Notify.onCreate(Notify.java:33)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1623)
... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1659)`

==> it seems you are trying to parse an empty string. You should include the parsing operation in a try/catch block and deal with malformed inputs.

Comment: in your stacktrace: `com.example.app.Notify.onCreate(Notify.java:33)` => line 33 of the Notify.java file. Which probably is the one you quoted.

Comment: thanks. This values is read from sharedpreferences. Can I check with an IF? if (value.isEqual(null)) { [...] } else { value = "value" } How I check if a string value is empty? thanks!

Comment: If `ListPreference` were null, you would get a NullPointerException. You can check for empty with `if(ListPreference.isEmpty()`, but I would simply use a try/catch block which will handle any malformed input, not just empty strings => more bullet proof.

Comment: Ok thanks. This value set a "fade on activities" so, at first time fade should be 1500. I think there's another bug. For now, can I resolve checking if value isEmpty() and if yes set to 1500 with try/catch or is better if if/else? thanks!

Comment: I would use: `try { fade = Integer.parseInt(ListPreference); } catch (Exception e) { /*log if you want*/ fade = 1500; }`

Answer (score 1):

as in log :

> NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer

you are trying to parse space to integer . before parsing string value to Integer check for null or empty

Answer (score 1):

Actually, There is any symbol or character happen in String `ListPreference`,

Its better to Handle this exception.

```
try {
     fade = Integer.parseInt(ListPreference);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        Log.e("Exception",e.toString());
}
```

**Update:**

Look at the **Jakarta Commons** :

[NumberUtils.isNumber()](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/math/NumberUtils.html#isNumber%28java.lang.String%29)

This can be used to check most whether a given String is a number.

Also before using `String ListPreference` just removed white space from it using `trim()`.

Using `ListPreference.trim()` and also check the length of `ListPreference` whether length is greater than 1 or not.

like, `ListPreference.length() > 1`